# change button image when play completes swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

sender button changes when i click play button but when i click another button in the tableview the button first button image not changes to play

```
 @IBAction func playSound(sender: UIButton) {
if self.player != nil && self.player.playing {
            player.stop()
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)            
        }
else {
sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal) 
}
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: if conditon {
          self.btnmale.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "imagename")!, forState: .Normal)
    }else {
          self.btnmale.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "imagename1")!, forState: .Normal)
    }

Comment: i have already did this see the code above

Comment: Did U use Tableview for create Play Audio file ?

Comment: yes i have a table view and then in table view cell i have sound button

Comment: Do you show me your UI of thats screen ?

Comment: when i click the button sound plays and the buttonImg changes to pause and it is left pause until u click it again and when i click another button it also changes to pause and the first button does't changes to play see the image

Comment: I will give you batter idea for play audio file in your view . just update your question with your play audio file UI

Comment: what title shall i provoide ?

Comment: Add one more image thats your audio file play i want to show it so add one more image in your question.

Comment: give me the answer

Comment: Do u Perform action on Button click or didSelectRowAtIndexPath table view select method ?

Comment: didselectRowAtInderxPath works when u click the cell but i m clicking the button

Answer (score 2):

```
**Try this code ...**  

 Declare one variable for get index.

 var songnamearray : NSArray = NSArray()
 var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
 var selectedindex : Int?
 var isFristtime : Bool = false



override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        songnamearray = ["Saiyaan (Sanam) 320Kbps(MajMasti.in)" ,"Phone Mein Teri Photo (Neha Kakkar) - 320 Kbps(GoldMusic.In)" ,"Mile Ho Tum Humko (Neha Kakkar) - 320 Kbps(GoldMusic.In)" ," Rain Mashup (Neha Kakkar) - 320 Kbps(GoldMusic.In)" ,"Car Mein Music Baja (Neha Kakkar) 320Kbps"]

    }



func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return songnamearray.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Songcell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

      // info 5 play 6 name 7
        let eventname: UILabel = (cell.viewWithTag(7) as! UILabel)

        let info: UIButton = (cell.viewWithTag(5) as! UIButton)
         let play: UIButton = (cell.viewWithTag(6) as! UIButton)
        if selectedindex == indexPath.row{
            if isFristtime == true
            {
                play.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause-button.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }else{
                play.setImage(UIImage(named: "play-button.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
        }else{
            play.setImage(UIImage(named: "play-button.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
        info.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon (5).png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        play.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.CloseMethod(_:event:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
        info.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.CloseMethod1(_:event:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
        eventname.text = songnamearray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String

        return cell

    }



@IBAction func CloseMethod(sender: UIButton, event: AnyObject) {

        let touches = event.allTouches()!
        let touch = touches.first!
        let currentTouchPosition = touch.locationInView(self.Songlisttable)
        let indexPath = self.Songlisttable.indexPathForRowAtPoint(currentTouchPosition)!
        selectedindex = indexPath.row
        if isFristtime == true
        {
            audioPlayer.pause()
            isFristtime = false
        }else{
            let songnamestring :  NSString  = songnamearray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! String
            do {
                if let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(songnamestring as String, ofType: "mp3") {
                    let alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: bundle)
                    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
                    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                    try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound)
                    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                    audioPlayer.play()
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

            isFristtime = true
        }
        self.Songlisttable.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: let play: UIButton = (cell.viewWithTag(11) as! UIButton)
this line shows compilation error

Comment: In your Storyboard tableviewcell play button give a tag 11 so your error gone.

Comment: No, stuck in the IF condition

Comment: What kind of error You face ? while app is running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124957/discussion-between-himanshu-moradiya-and-sajjad-aims).

Comment: @SajjadAims approve my this answer because some user face same problem that you face so i can suggest my answer . thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try to set background image for button

```
let image = UIImage(named: "play.png") as UIImage
sender.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is that call radio button. I never use radio button in cell. It is hard for me. I'm newbie. If U need it, it is that: [Radio button logic in UItableViewCells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638489/radio-button-logic-in-uitableviewcells). 
But i use other way: didSelectRowAtIndexPath. When u click in cell, button current is show pause image, and other button is show play image. U can reference it

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    currentIndexPath = indexPath;
    YourTableViewCell *cell = nil;

    if (!previousIndexPath) {
        previousIndexPath = currentIndexPath;
    } 
    if (previousIndexPath != currentIndexPath) {
        cell = (YourTableViewCell *) [_yourTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:previousIndexPath];
        [cell.radioBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cell = (YourTableViewCell *) [_yourTableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:currentIndexPath];
        [cell.radioBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        previousIndexPath = currentIndexPath;
    }


    if (previousIndexPath == currentIndexPath) {
        cell = (YourTableViewCell *) [_yourTableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:previousIndexPath];
        [cell.radioBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: this method is implementing when u click the cell but i m not clicking on cell i m clicking on button in the cell

Comment: I know, U need read: link Radio button logic in UItableViewCells in my ans. It is solution for U. Using delegate

Comment: i implemented your answer but not working , DidSelectedRow.. is related to click on cell rather than button, i want just click on buttons,

Comment: Oh no. Radio button logic in UItableViewCells is click on button in cell. It's not my way.