# iOS swift UIButton in TableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `tableView` with custom cell. in my custom `cell` I have a like button. for like Button I wrote a function to change state from `.normal` to `.selected` like this:

FeedViewCell

```
class FeedViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton!


var likes : Bool {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "likes")
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "likes")
    }
}
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "like-btn-active"), for: .selected)
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@IBAction func likeBtnTouch(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    print("press")
    // toggle the likes state
    self.likes = !self.likeButton.isSelected
    // set the likes button accordingly
    self.likeButton.isSelected = self.likes
 }
}
```

FeedViewController :

```
class FeedViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var feedTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Register Cell Identifier
    let feedNib = UINib(nibName: "FeedViewCell", bundle: nil)
    self.feedTableView.register(feedNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "FeedCell")
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(_ tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.feeds.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeedCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedViewCell

   return cell
 }
}
```

But my problem is when I tap like button in cell with `indexPath.row 0` the state of button in cell with `indexPath.row 3` change state too.

where is my mistake?

thanks

Comment: Please add more code. How are you linking the `@IBAction` with your button?

Comment: dear @Adeel I have a xib file and connect `@IBAction` to button with control + drag

Comment: Actually your question is not clear so it's hard to asses what might be going wrong here. I would suggest you to add more code of your `viewController` and the `FeedViewCell`.

Comment: thanks dear @Adeel I add all line of code in `FeedViewController` and `FeedViewCell`

Comment: not quite relevant but why are you saving the state of the button to `UserDefaults` when it changes?

Comment: and please add a screenshots of your mobile/simulator when the button is selected and when it is unselected.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848110/change-button-image-when-play-completes-swift/39850431#39850431 refer my this answer same functionality but with different purpose .

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya can you please give me more detail? I don't understand your solution in that link. thanks

Comment: @Adeel it because if I don't use UserDefaults when scroll tableView the state of button back to `norma`l

Comment: @MohammadReza you want to perform some action on tableview inside cell button that you so you can use my code for perform some action on button for particular cell .

Comment: thanks dear @HimanshuMoradiya, but nothing change and problem still exist

Comment: @MohammadReza in my that code i perform audio player in tableview cell music play and stop with button icon change like play and pause . at that postion you can set like or dislike icon .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125685/discussion-between-mohammadreza-and-himanshu-moradiya).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post all your code, but I can tell you that for this to work the `@IBAction func likeBtnTouch(_ sender: AnyObject) { }` definition must be inside the `FeedViewCell` class definition to make it unique to a particular instance of the cell.

Comment: dear @warby I add `@IBAction func likeBtnTouch(_ sender: AnyObject) { }` in my FeedViewCell class but problem still exist.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, I normally ensure that all the UI elements inside my cell are populated in cellForRowAtIndexPath when using dequeued cells.  Also it should be set from an external source.  I.o.w not from a property inside the cell.  Dequeuing cells reuse them, and if not setup properly, it might have some leftovers from another cell.

For example, inside cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
self.likeButton.isSelected = likeData[indexPath.row]
```