# I want to perform get display a different controller on clicking respective button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have designed a button on `UITableViewCell`, on loading I get 3 `buttons`. I want to display a different screen on clicking respective buttons, I tried tag with selector. May I know any other possibilities.

I tried `tag=0` to `tag = 2`;

Any other possibilities??

Comment: Show your UI for better understanding of what you exactly want...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848110/change-button-image-when-play-completes-swift/39850431#39850431 refer this answer your problem solve

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
..........

     [cell.btnMore addTarget:self action:@selector(clickOnMoreButton:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [cell.btnSpeaker addTarget:self action:@selector(clickOnSpeakerButton:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [cell.btnClipBoard addTarget:self action:@selector(clickOnClipBoardButton:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

.......
}
```

Handle click event

```
-(IBAction)clickOnMoreButton:(id)sender event:(id)event {
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    NSDictionary *dic = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have taken the button in the cell. You need to assign a tag to it and add target to the button.

Here in the code my custom table cell has a button named `btnCompltSurvey`. You can see how I have set the tag and target method to the button in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SurveyCell";
    FeedBackTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    cell.btnCompltSurvey.tag = 100 + indexPath.row;
    [cell.btnCompltSurvey addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCompleteSurveyClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    return cell;
}
```

Then define the target method here like this

```
-(void)btnCompleteSurveyClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSInteger index = sender.tag-100;
    NSLog(@"index clicked %ld",(unsigned long)index);

    //Write the condition
    
switch (index) {
    case 0:
        //Code to navigate to required VC, let's say 1st VC
        break;
    case 1:
        //Code to navigate to required VC, let's say 2nd VC
        break;
        
    default:
        break;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend UITableViewCell and and create button in it pass the required data to the cell when you deque the cell. If a user selects button you will get call back in the extended class in that way you can get the indexpath and perform the code whatever you want