# Show a second ImageView on UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton, uiimage

I want to add an extra image on the UIButton if my condition is true.
This means that if the result of my condition is:

1) "false", then the UIButton should contain one image.

2) "true", then the UIButton should contain one more additional image.

Comment: If condition is true do you want to replace Image 1 with Image 2?

Comment: I want to add an extra image on the UIButton if my condition is true

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change button image when play completes swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848110/change-button-image-when-play-completes-swift)

Comment: Simply, try `SetImage` as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add 2 images, add them under your button.

In order to stretch the first image, set constraint of the width of the second image = 0 and set constraint of the space between the images = 0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want Image 1 to become Image 2 you would use

```
yourButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "image2.png"), for: .normal)
```

If you want to show Image 1 and Image 2 at the same time, you will need to manually create the image with 1 and 2 in, **save it** and add to the **project assets**.

Then use the code above to set the image to the one with both images in.
However, doing this I imagine you will need to use a bigger button to accommodate the new image.

Use this to set the frame of the button use the width and height of the new image at the same time you change at the correct x and y

```
yourButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
```